# Need to search for string in text file and do something if string is NOT found

Tags: c#

I am trying to write C# code to search for a specific string in a text file, and display which line it was found on or display a message if it can not find the string. I have tried several different pieces of code, but they will only do something if it finds the string. If I put an else statement to display the text not found message, it ignores it if the string is not found. Using a "while" loop ends without doing anything or it displays the "string not found" message even if the string is found. I have tried for loops and foreach loops, and still not getting the results I am looking for. The text file has one word per line.

Here is the code I have:

```
public long CountLinesReader(string file)
{
  var lineCounter = 0L;
  using (StreamReader reader = new(file))
  {
    while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
    {
      lineCounter++;
    }
    return lineCounter;
  }
}

private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StrSearchTerm = TxtSearchTerm.Text;
  StrTextFile = @Application.StartupPath + @"\TextFile.txt";
  IntLineCount = (int)CountLinesReader(StrTextFile);
  for(int i = 0; i < IntLineCount; i++) 
  {
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(StrTextFile);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      StrLine = line;
      if(StrLine == StrSearchTerm)
      {
        LblSearch.Text = StrSearchTerm + " found on line: "+ i.ToString();
      }
    }
    if (StrLine == string.Empty)
    {
      LblSearch.Text = "The word: " + StrSearchTerm + " not found.";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following method to find the line numbers where the search text appears. If the search text is not found in the file then the method returns an empty list.

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches the specified file for a given word.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">Full path of the file.</param>
/// <param name="word">Search text.</param>
/// <returns>The line numbers of the occurences.</returns>
public List<int> SearchWord(string filePath, string word)
{
    var occurences = new List<int>();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string currentLine = lines[i];
        if (currentLine.Contains(word))
        {
            occurences.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return occurences;
}
```

To use the method from a `Button` click handler:

```
private void BtnSearchFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = @"D:\Test.txt";
    string word = TxtSearchTerm.Text;
    List<int> occurences = SearchWord(filePath, word);
    if (occurences.Any())
    {
        string lines = string.Join(",", occurences);
        string message = $"The word '{word}' occurs in lines {lines}";
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
    else
    {
        string message = $"The word '{word}' could not be found in the file.";
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

The result (when found):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = "path/to/your/textfile.txt";
        string searchString = "your search string";

        bool found = false;
        int lineNumber = 0;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNumber++;
                if (line.Contains(searchString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"String found on line {lineNumber}: {line}");
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String not found in the file.");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```